# Django form not saving at all

Tags: django

I have registered the form in the admin page put the form data doesn't save only the name of the class shows in the admin page. And the terminal doesn't give me error. what could I be doing wrong

this is my views.py

```
    def details_investor_business(request):
        Invest_form=Investor_form(request.POST)
        business_form=Business_owner_form(request.POST)
        if Invest_form.is_valid():
            iform=Invest_form.save()
        if business_form.is_valid():
            bform=business_form.save()
        context={}
        context['Iform']=Invest_form
        context['Bform']=business_form
        return render(request,'detail.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
      class Investor_form(forms.ModelForm):
         class Meta:
             model=Investor_Registration
             fields=("__all__")
```

models.py

```
     class Investor_Registration(models.Model):

           investor_fullname=models.CharField(default="Jon   Samuel",max_length=50,null="True")
           Address=models.TextField(default='Resendential Address')
           Age=models.IntegerField()
           Gender=models.CharField(choices=gender,max_length=50)
           Figi_Username=models.CharField(default='Figi Username',blank=True,max_length=50)
           Next_of_Kin=models.CharField(default='Next of kin Name',max_length=50)
           Next_of_Kin_Address=models.TextField(default='Address of Next of kin',max_length=100)
           Bank_Name=models.CharField(default='GTB',max_length=50)
           Bank_Type=models.CharField(choices=typeBank,max_length=50)


     def __str__(self):
             return(self.investor_fullname,    self.Address,self.Age,self.Gender,self.Figi_Username,self.Next_of_Kin,self.Next_of_Kin_Address,self.Bank_Name,self.Bank_Type)
```

Comment: Use this   `fields="__all__"`

Comment: What do you mean, you "registered" this form in the admin page. How did you do that? Your view doesn't seem to have anything to do with the admin.

Comment: I am referring to my model, this admin.site.register(BusinessOwner_Registration)
admin.site.register(Investor_Registration)
admin.site.register(User)

Comment: @Rahman where should I use that I have use that in forms.py already..